# Controlling variables from keyboard bash scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, input, scripting

I need to control 2 variables using k and j keys. Now, I have this solution

```
read -s -n 1 -t 0.1 keys
    if [[ "$keys" == k ]]; then
        wpm=$(($wpm+10)) 
            if [[ "$wpm" -gt 1000 ]]; then
            wpm=$(($wpm-10))
            fi
    fi
    if [[ "$keys" == j ]]; then
        wpm=$(($wpm-10)) 
            if [[ "$wpm" -lt 100 ]]; then
            wpm=$(($wpm+10))
            fi
    fi
```

It is not elegant and it is glitching. I know there are bind command, but I need to give this script to users and Im not sure they would bother with source(which solve "Warning: line editing not enabled" command.

Is there any other ways to do it?

Comment: No wonder it's glitching - why use 0.1s timeout?

Comment: You can put `bind` commands at the top of your script, but it's not really clear what context this is in. In any case, `bash` is not a great language for this kind of real-time interactive use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No wonder it's glitching - why use 0.1s timeout? –  suspectus

suspectus asked a good question. user3047492, just drop the `-t 0.1` (unless there are further requirements about which you kept quiet).